# Deadlock error in azure datawarehouse

Tags: database, deadlock, azure-synapse

I am getting this error when querying/deleting some rows from large tables in azure sql-dw . `[40001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Transaction (Process ID 144) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction. (1205) (SQLExecDirectW)')`
I am pretty sure no other process is reading the same table at that time (as its newly created test table by me , so no other consumers)

I want to understand which processes are causing deadlock . Is there way to get deadlock graph and get some sense out of it ?

Comment: In sql server, I solve this problem with this command.  `set transaction isolation level read uncommitted;`.  I have that command in my Azure DW stored procedures as well and don't have deadlocks.  However, I don't know whether or not the lack of deadlocks is due to that command,.

Comment: What DWU is your DW? Gen1 or 2?

Answer (score 1):

KBR,

It is not possible for me to give you a full answer based on the information provided. It could be a interquery deadlock.

Feel free to open a [Support Case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-get-started-create-support-ticket) with the Data Warehouse Support team and can troubleshoot this with you.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try the below snippet:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) AS [target_data_XML] FROM sys.fn_xe_telemetry_blob_target_read_file('dl', null, null, null))

SELECT [db_name], [wait_resource], [deadlock_xml] FROM (
    SELECT target_data_XML.query('/event/data[@name=''database_name'']/value').value('(/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [db_name],
    waitresource_node.value('@waitresource', 'nvarchar(250)') AS [wait_resource],
    deadlock_node.query('.') as [deadlock_xml]
    FROM CTE CROSS APPLY target_data_XML.nodes('(/event/data/value/deadlock)') AS T(deadlock_node)
    CROSS APPLY target_data_XML.nodes('(/event/data/value/deadlock/process-list/process)') AS U(waitresource_node)
) deadlock

WHERE [db_name] = '<YourDB>'
AND [wait_resource] = '<wait_resource>'
```